# Sverchok file doesn't work in Blender 2.93

Tags: python, error, sverchok

I just started learning Sverchok and created a group node (in Blender 2.92).

[image: Working node in 2.92]

I still have it open on one machine (Manjaro Linux).
I wanted to work on it on my laptop (also Manjaro) which already has Blender 2.93.
If I load the file, the Groupped Node is stated as Undefined:

[image: Broken in 2.93]

In the Terminal there are lot's of Errors:

[image: Terminal with Errors]

Is this related to the Python difference between Blender and Sverchok?

I'm scared to restart my PC as it also had the Update to Blender 2.93...

Not a great start for me and Sverchok. :-(

Is there a workaround or a solution for this?

Comment: Suggest try the *latest release* instead of downloading the master: https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/releases/tag/vstable10 Otherwise consider to file a bug report over at github so the devs get noticed (a few of them hanging around here as well).

Comment: i had contact to a sverchok developer and he told me not to use monad because it won't maintained anymore. He advised me to use the "normal" group node.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the comments! The latest release solved the problem. I could open the file and replace some deprecated nodes. Chris, I was a bit confused because there are 3 ways to group nodes: CTRL-G creates a Monad, then there is "Add Group Node" in the Sverchock Add Menu and there is the "Node" menu in the TitleBar where the standard Blender Make Group entry is but that one is grayed out. So it's a bit confusing, especially that the hot key creates a soon to be deprecated group. Now I know how to do it properly. Thanks!

Comment: If you need help on Sverchok you can also create issues on their GitHub site. They answer very quick.

Comment: Super! Thanks Chris! I will do that, especially as these kind of questions are apparently not welcomed here. (This got closed because it's Off-Topic, which is strange as Sverchok is Blender only and there are many Sverchok related questions here.)